# Writable Issue: Not able to print the contents

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, writable

My input value to reducer is a double array.

```
719.000 501.000 -75.000
 501.000 508.000 -62.000
 -75.000 -62.000 10.000
```

In my reducer i need to print this matrix.so i did

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key,
            Iterable<DoubleArrayWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            System.out.println("in reducer");
            for (DoubleArrayWritable  c :values) { // TODO - test me 
                System.out.println("C ="+c.toString());
}
}
```

where DoubleArrayWritable is

```
public static class DoubleArrayWritable extends TwoDArrayWritable {
        public DoubleArrayWritable() {
            super(DoubleWritable.class);
        }
    }
```

My output is `C =edu.Driver$DoubleArrayWritable@32d16fe3`
But i need to print entire matrix in human readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `toString()` of `DoubleArrayWritable`:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    // return the string you want
}
```